# Recursively find filenames of exactly 8 hex characters, but not all 0-9, no lookahead (Mac terminal, bash)

Tags: regex, bash, macos, find

I'm trying to write a regex to find files recursively with Mac Terminal (bash, not zsh even though Catalina wants me to switch over for whatever reason) using the find command. I'm looking for files that are:

- Exactly 8 hexadecimal digits (0-9 and A-F)
- But NOT only decimal digits (0-9)

In other words, it would match A1234567, ABC12DEF, 12345ABC, and ABCDABCD, but not 12345678 or 09876543.

To find files that are exactly 8 hex digits, I've used this:

```
find -E . -type f -regex '.*/[A-F0-9]{8}'
```

The .*/ is necessary to allow the full path name to precede the filename. This is eventually going to get fed to **rm**, so I have to keep the path.

It SEEMS like this should work to fulfill both of my requirements:

```
find -E . -type f -regex '.*/(?![0-9]{8})[A-F0-9]{8}'
```

But that returns an error:

```
find: -regex: .*/(?![0-9]{8})[A-F0-9]{8}: repetition-operator operand invalid
```

It seems like the find command doesn't support lookaheads. How can I do this without one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With any POSIX-compliant `find`

```
find . -type f                 \
       -name '????????'        \
     ! -name '*[![:xdigit:]]*' \
       -name '*[![:digit:]]*'
```

And if you insist on using regexps for this, here you go

```
find -E . -type f                     \
          -regex '.*/[[:xdigit:]]{8}' \
        ! -regex '.*/[[:digit:]]*'
```

Those who use GNU find should drop `-E` and insert `-regextype posix-extended` after paths to make this work.

Comment: I don't insist on a particular method as long as it does what I need to do, though I appreciate having multiple ways to solve a problem. I didn't know about POSIX bracket expressions at all previously, so thanks for telling me about those.

I'm no programmer, just trying to do an uncommon task more efficiently. I'm going to stick -exec rm {} \; at the end of this command (after a trial run with -i just to be sure). Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

It's probably easiest to just filter out the results you don't like:

`find -E . -type f -regex '.*/[A-F0-9]{8}' -print | egrep -v '.*/[0-9]{8}$'`

```
$ find -E . -type f -regex '.*/[A-F0-9]{8}' -print
./01234567
./ABCDEFAF
./ABCDEF01
./ABCDEF2A
./ABCDEFA2
./x/01234567
./x/ABCDEFAF
./x/ABCDEF01
./x/ABCDEF2A
./x/ABCDEFA2
```

```
$ find -E . -type f -regex '.*/[A-F0-9]{8}' -print | egrep -v '.*/[0-9]{8}$'
./01234567
./ABCDEFAF
./ABCDEF01
./ABCDEF2A
./ABCDEFA2
./x/01234567
./x/ABCDEFAF
./x/ABCDEF01
./x/ABCDEF2A
./x/ABCDEFA2
```

Comment: In this particular case, I see no need to pipe the output of `find` to another _command_ to do the filtering when `find` can do exactly what was expressed in the OP. See the answer posted by oguz ismail.

Answer (score 0):

My `find` didn't understand `-E` and was inexplicably grumpy about `-regex` in general, but this still worked:

```
find . -type f -name '[A-F0-9][A-F0-9][A-F0-9][A-F0-9][A-F0-9][A-F0-9][A-F0-9][A-F0-9]' -a -name '*[A-F]*'
```

Not as elegant as [oguz ismail](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10248678/oguz-ismail)'s, but easier to read for my clogged brain, lol

Comment: The OP is tagged `macos` and also said "with Mac Terminal (bash...", so what version of **macOS** are you running that `find` doesn't accept the `-E` _option_?

Comment: I think this is the solution I was originally heading towards, but I didn't realize find could accept more than one -name argument...